# Maximising output amplitude

Tags: transistors, bjt, emitter-follower

How can I modify this emitter follower circuit to get maximum amplitude output with no distortion?

Re = 2.25k ohms, Rb1 = 57.3k ohms, Rb2 = 96.1

I currently have 0.96 gain

Vcc is limited to 9 V and a collector current of 2 mA for RB1 and RB2, for a bias-stable network we use the × general rule  =  .

[image]

Comment: You can set VCC and the resistor values appropriately. Note you also need an appropriate input amplitude. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @BrianDrummond Ive been limited to using a 5 V peak to peak 50 kHz

Comment: How would I modify the resistor values and Vcc to increase amplitude gain?

Comment: What gain are you seeing at the moment? You should be able to get pretty close to 1.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I have 0.96 gain at the moment

Comment: Im just questioning which resistor values should be increased/decreased to get closer to unity gain

Comment: Add that info to the question. We don' play guessing games here. What gain do you want? What Vcc is available? What voltage are you biassing the base to?

Comment: *How would I modify the resistor values and Vcc to increase amplitude gain?* **Not**, you have made a **common collector circuit** and that type of circuit has certain (fixed, you cannot change it) properties regarding its signal gain. The 0.96 times gain you have is what is to be expected. If you want more gain go find the **common emitter circuit** and study it and what signal gain it has.

Comment: The only things we know so far are the coupling capacitor values and the load impedance (1 Meg). There are several potential sources of attenuation here. Calculate teh input impedance. What is its loss at your frequency with your chosen input capacitance? And so on for every aspect of the design that could reduce amplitude.

Comment: Suffice to say that **experienced EEs** who want a gain of 1 (exactly one) would use an **opamp** and build a **buffer**. Sure it can be done with a single transistor as well but not with a common collector. Answer us this question: **Why** do you think a common collector circuit is a good choice to get a signal gain of unity? What makes you think that the gain = 1 is even achievable?

Comment: "which resistor values should be increased/decreased to get closer to unity gain" - to get unity gain, remove all the resistors, capacitors, and the transistor, and replace them with a short from input to output. This will also provide maximum amplitude without distortion!

Comment: if Rb1 = 57.3k ohms, Rb2 = 96.1 I'm surprised it works at all, as the DC at the base is almost at 0V. I suppose you mean 96.1k, but these are still odd values. So is the emitter resistor, this is typically low to give low output Z, the value you have would make the curcuit kind of pointless. Normally you would bias such a circuit so that the emitter was close to mid rail, to get maximum voltage swing. Is this a homework question by any chance?